# My tensorflow/keras CNN does not improve over epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm building a CNN for binary image classification. For some reason, accuracy does not improve over epochs, giving me the same result for epoch 1 and epochs 2, 3, etc. Here is my model:

```
  num_classes = 2
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)])

  model.compile(
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01),
  loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

  model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=2,
  shuffle = True)
```

I have tried the following:

-Changing the optimizer from Adam to sgd.

-Using only relu, only sigmoid, relu and softmax, sigmoid and softmax as activation functions.

-Changing learning rate.

-Adding or subtracting convolutional and pooling layers.

-Changing loss function from BinaryCrossEntropt to CategoricalCrossEntropy.

-A mix of the above.

With all of these changes, the problem stays the same, my accuracy does not improve or change at all over epochs. The data is supposed to be fine in principle.

Comment: For how many epochs did you train that did not show any change in the accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

- Visualize your train and test dataset. Has the test dataset a same overall distribution as the train dataset? If test dataset deviates a lot from train dataset, you'll have permanently bad accuracy.
- Is the data normalized before input? Either column or row-wise normalization to make the input values small 0 <= input_value <= 1 has often a positive effect on learning.

Comment: please show code for train and test data